# How can I write connectiong for Access database?

Tags: asp.net

I am working with MS Access databse for the first time. I deployed my appilcaton on my server. I have access database on my system (D:\Database).

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="dbcon" value="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=  ?  "/>

</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
```

When I am trying to connect it is giving error.

How can I modify my connection string?

Regards,
NS

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the database have an extension of `.mdb`, otherwise change it to whatever is needed:

```
<add key="dbcon" value="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Database.mdb"/>
```

So all you needed to do was to add the name of the db file to the connection string.

You can find more samples [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access).

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
// TODO: Modify the connection string and include any
// additional required properties for your database.
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
@"Data source= C:\Documents and Settings\username\" +
@"My Documents\AccessFile.mdb";
```

now modify your connection:

```
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["dbcon"] =  conn.ConnectionString;//the new connection;
```

[Read more ...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ybdbtte%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)